# Can't use @ operator on s4 objects stored in a list in R?

Tags: r, list, r-s4

This is hard to make a reproducible example of so I am sorry in advance.

I have a list called `mp3List` that contains `wave` objects. I generate it like this: It populates a list with 100 wave objects produced with `readMP3`.

```
mp3List <- vector("list", 100)
for(i in UrlReadNames)
{
  mp3List[which(UrlReadNames == i)]<-readMP3(i)
}
```

The structure of a wave object looks like this:

```
> str(ddd)
Formal class 'Wave' [package "tuneR"] with 6 slots
..@ left     : int [1:14772096] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
..@ right    : int [1:14772096] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
..@ stereo   : logi TRUE
..@ samp.rate: num 44100
..@ bit      : num 16
..@ pcm      : logi TRUE
```

The structure of a wave object in a list looks like this:

```
> str(mp3List[1])
List of 1

 $ :Formal class 'Wave' [package "tuneR"] with 6 slots
 .. ..@ left     : int [1:14772096] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 .. ..@ right    : int [1:14772096] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 .. ..@ stereo   : logi TRUE
 .. ..@ samp.rate: num 44100
 .. ..@ bit      : num 16
 .. ..@ pcm      : logi TRUE
```

Now I try to use `mp3List[1]@left` to access this part of the object, but I get this error: `Error: Attempting to get a "left" slot from an object of a basic class ("list") without slots`

I want to use @ on these objects in the list so I can write for loops to access every wave object in the list without having to pull out each one individually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[` on a list returns a sublist. To *extract* an individual component, use `[[`.

```
mp3List[[1]]@left
```

Comment: yup, so simple, thanks for the answer, forgot about list structures, I will accept when my time limit is over.